# assembleRelease task failed when building a Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build

Building with sound null safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find builder-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.1.0/builder-4.1.0.jar
> Could not find bundletool-0.14.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.14.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.14.0/bundletool-0.14.0.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           10.9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Post your build gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build your project with following three steps:

1- `flutter build apk --debug`

2- `flutter build apk --profile`

3- `flutter build apk --release`